# RN remote debugging "TypeError: freeProcess.binding"

Tags: react-native, google-chrome-devtools

I was wondering if anyone else saw an error like this while trying to do remote JS debugging in Chrome.

> TypeError: freeProcess.binding is not a function

I don't have any errors when I am not using the debugger.

I am on 0.32RN and 15.3.1React.

Comment: FWIW https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9256

Comment: @wOxxOm It was worth all the while.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but you can try to **disable "Pause on Caught Exceptions" in Chrome.**

I met the same issue and I solved it by doing this.